# Attach a Javascript function to an OOTB ribbon button

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to attach a custom javascript function to the out of the box "Download a copy" ribbon button. This is to provide analytics for file downloads done through the ribbon button.

I tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Trackdownloads");

    function Trackdownloads(){

        debugger;
        $("a[id='Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Download-Large']").live( "click", 
                  function() {
                      alert('hello');
                  }
            );

    }

    </script>
```

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem.
Actually, attaching a javascript function to the button is not the right way to implement this.
The correct implementation is to replace the OOTB button with a custom button, and call a custom javascript function to carry out the desired action.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407619.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to override a button in the ribbon. Creating a custom Page Component is a good idea. Example:

```
Type.registerNamespace('Company.Project.Ribbon.PageComponent');

Company.Project.Ribbon.PageComponent = function (PageComponentId) {
    this._pageComponentId = PageComponentId;
    Company.Project.Ribbon.PageComponent.initializeBase(this);
}

Company.Project.Ribbon.PageComponent.prototype =
{
    _pageComponentId: "PageComponentIDHolder",

    getId: function () {
        return this._pageComponentId;
    },
    init: function () {
        this._myCommandList = ['DownloadCopy'];
        this._myHandledCommands = {};
        this._myHandledCommands['DownloadCopy'] = Function.createDelegate(this, this.CMD1_Handler);
    },
    getFocusedCommands: function () {
        return this._myCommandList; 
    },
    getGlobalCommands: function () {
        return this._myCommandList; 
    },
    canHandleCommand: function (commandId) {
        var canHandle = this._myHandledCommands[commandId];

        if (canHandle)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    },
    handleCommand: function (commandId, properties, sequence) {
        return this._myHandledCommands[commandId](commandId, properties, sequence);
    },
    isFocusable: function () {
        return true;
    },
    CMD1_Handler: function (commandId, properties, sequence) {
        alert('Download a copy-button was clicked');
    }
}

Company.Project.Ribbon.PageComponent.registerClass('Company.Project.Ribbon.PageComponent', CUI.Page.PageComponent)
NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("/_layouts/custompagecomponents/PageComponent.js");



function init2() {
    var instance = new Company.Project.Ribbon.PageComponent("ComponentID");
    SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().addPageComponent(instance);
}

function init1() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init2, 'sp.ribbon.js');
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init1, '/_layouts/custompagecomponents/PageComponent.js');
```